# How to include specific function declarations in a .cpp file of an external library without including the entire file

Tags: c++, opencv, include, derived-class

OpenCV's OpenCL feature extraction source code has some functions I'd like to use; however they are not defined in the usual include header path but rather directly in the source file in [modules/src/hog.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.9.x-prep/modules/ocl/src/hog.cpp) under the namespace cv::ocl::device::hog at the top.

What is the correct way to access those functions? I don't think I should just include the entire source file again. In fact I did try that, but the compiler is unable to find some dependencies.

I would rather not have to change the OpenCV source directly and then repatch everything when OpenCV 3.0.0 comes out, so I've been trying to write a derived class of cv::ocl::HOGDescriptor to do what I want.

Comment: If the header do not include it, it is probably an internal function that developers may no longer continue, change, rename, etc. It seem a very bad idea to use it. Why not to rewrite your own function?

Comment: You normally do not include source files from libraries (or source files in general but that is a different topic). You use the libraries public/external headers and link to the library.

Comment: The function is used internally in the detectMultiScale function, which is in the public header files. However I want to change the features used slightly in that function. I don't really know OpenCL myself, and it would take me too long to write the entire thing from scratch. I realize you normally use functionl from external headers, but I'm asking if there is a way to use these functions.

Comment: I assume detectMultiScale is not a virtual function? In that case I would copy the source and header to your project and rename the class and change the implementation of detectMultiScale.

Comment: detectMultiScale is more or less just a wrapper which calls a bunch of other functions in that file. The problem is, I can't seem to access the other functions in that file...